# How to compare a single array to a multidimensional array and get the field name from the multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: arrays, laravel, loops, foreach, collections

Right now, I can get the `driver id's` in `positions` table in an array format and the `employees` data in `employees` table by using eloquent.

```html
public function getDrivers() {
        $driver_ids = Positions::where('name', '=', 'Driver')->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $position_ids = Employees::all()->toArray();

        return $driver_ids;
}
```

How can I get the `first_name` and `last_name` values from `employees` table if one of the `$driver_ids` matches the values from the `position_id` fields in `employees` table? Currently, the `$position_ids` gets all data from `employees` table.

I've tried using foreach's but can't get it right.

The `$driver_ids` returns this data in single array:

```html
[
  1,
  6
]
```

While the `$position_ids` returns multidimensional array:

```js
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Lyle",
    "last_name": "Lucius",
    "designation_id": [
      2
    ],
    "position_id": [
      7,
      9
    ],
    "basic_pay": "784.00",
    "cost_classification": "Indirect Labor",
    "created_at": "2022-04-12T03:06:20.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-04-12T03:06:20.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "Shaeleigh",
    "last_name": "Jesse",
    "designation_id": [
      2
    ],
    "position_id": [
      6
    ],
    "basic_pay": "955.00",
    "cost_classification": "Indirect Labor",
    "created_at": "2022-04-12T06:38:31.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2022-04-12T06:38:31.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null
  }
]
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your getDrivers function try:

```
$driver_ids = Positions::where('name', '=', 'Driver')->pluck('id')->toArray();

$position_ids = Employees::whereIn('position_id', $driver_ids)->toArray();

return $driver_ids;
```

The whereIn method removes elements from the collection that do not have a specified item value that is contained within the given array. You can find the documentation in https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-wherein

Comment: It should be return `$position_ids` and remove `toArray()`. It didn't work as `position_id` is an array, not just an integer. The first argument in the `whereIn` should be an integer for an ID.